# Have ImageViews overlap when reaching edge of layout

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-linearlayout, overlap

Beginner developer here - I'm creating a card game in Android Studio using java, and I have cards (ImageViews) being created on the click of a button in my Horizontal LinearLayout.  Everything is working great, but when the objects get to the edge of the mobile screen, they just disappear as they are created.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a programmatic way to detect the edge of the screen, and then have the cards start to overlap with each other as more are created.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can get the device width and check if the current card distance from  start is less than or greater than the width of the device. if it is great, then you will start will the beginning again.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without seeing the actual layout code, but I would try to implement

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

for the parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of the screen as follows.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point p = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = p.x;
int height = p.y;
```

This will return the height and width in pixels as specified by [getSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29)

Think of the screen as a grid/coordinate system with top left being (x,y) = (0,0) and increasing as you move down towards bottom right.

Using the above information you should able to figure out when card is going off screen

Note: beware of screen rotation and handle it appropriately.